# Prove ${( 1- p)^{1-N}}( \Gamma (1+ \delta )-\sum_{n = 0}^{N - 2} (1-p)^n\frac{\Gamma (n+1+\delta )}{\Gamma (n + 1)}p^{\delta + 1} ) \ge0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to prove $g\ge 0$, where $$g = \frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 - p} \right)}^{N - 1}}}}\left( {\Gamma (1 + \delta ) - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 2} {{{\left( {1 - p} \right)}^n}\frac{{\Gamma (n + 1 + \delta )}}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}{p^{\delta  + 1}}} } \right).$$ Here, $p \ge 0$, $p\neq 1$,$\,\,N = 2,3,...,\,\,0 \le \delta  \le 1$. By matlab, it shows that $g\ge 0$ always holds. However, I cannot prove it. Can anyone give me some hints on this?

Comment: If MatLab shows that it *always* holds, then what more proof do you need? ;)

Comment: I want to prove it in theory.

Comment: What does that mean? You don't trust that your computer can produce a proof that this *always* works?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to exploit the integral representation for $\Gamma(z+1)$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}(1-p)^n p^{\delta+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+1+\delta)}{\Gamma(n+1)}&=&\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}\frac{(1-p)^n}{n!}p^{\delta+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{n+\delta}e^{-z}\,dz\\&<&\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(1-p)^n}{n!}p^{\delta+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{n+\delta}e^{-z}\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}p^{\delta+1}z^\delta e^{-pz}\,dz=\Gamma(\delta+1).\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Does this inequality hold for $p>1$?